# hive load data from comma separated list of absolute file paths

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, partitioning, oozie

With reference to the following hive command :

`LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INPATH 'filepath' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]`

Can I give a comma separated list of absolute file paths?
`LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://foo/bar1,hdfs://foo/bar2' INTO TABLE foo1`

The actual Use case I am looking for :

While using

```
<datasets>
      <dataset name="input1">
         <uri-template>hdfs://foo/bar/a</uri-template>
      </dataset>
</datasets>
<input-events>
      <data-in name="coordInput1" dataset="input1">
          <start-instance>${coord:current(-23)}</start-instance>
          <end-instance>${coord:current(0)}</end-instance>
      </data-in>
</input-events>
<action>
  <workflow>
         ...
     <configuration>
       <property>
          <name>input_files</name>
          <value>${coord:dataIn('coordInput1')}</value>
       </property>
     </configuration>
  </workflow>
 </action>
```

in co-ordinator.xml, assume there is a qualified set of 24 hdfs locations as my input. 
And if my hive query is some sort of loading the data into a table from all these locations, I want to use it like :
CREATE TABLE table1(
col1 STRING
)LOCATION (${input_files});

But, that doesn't work properly in hive.
Assume : input_files resolves to be `hdfs://foo/bar/1,hdfs://foo/bar/2,hdfs://foo/bar/3` this doesn't turn out be valid location in hive.

Only way I understand to achieve this is, run a java mapper which takes `input_files` as input and output a dynamic hive script which runs

```
`LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://foo/bar/1' INTO TABLE foo1`
`LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://foo/bar/2' INTO TABLE foo1`
```

separately.

So, finally, the question I have is , when I am able to resolve my entire data-set of interest, which I am able to use as `${coord:dataIn('coordInput1')}`, can't I leverage this to hive, avoiding individual `LOAD DATA..` or `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITIONS..` statements individually ?

Comment: i have the same problem in this moment. have you got some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use java action node to do this logic. You can split input_files using comma and use hive jdbc connection for executing hive commands in a loop for all input locations.